# Discrepancy in probability calculations in paper 'Multi-digit Number Recognition...'

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network

In the paper, '[Goodfellow, I., et al. Multi-digit Number Recognition from Street View Imagery using Deep Convolutional Neural Networks. ICLR, 2014](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6082)', on page 10 there is a table which calculate $\log(P(S|H))$ given $\log(P(s_1,s_2,...,s_l))$ and $\log(P(l))$.

From the equation given in page 4 it should be

$$\log(P(S|H)) = \log(P(s_1,s_2,...,s_l)) + \log(P(l))$$

but if you see from the first two lines in the lower table it is:

$$\log(P(S|H)) = 10\cdot\log(P(s_1,s_2,...,s_l)) + \log(P(l))$$

and on third line it is correctly specified as:

$$\log(P(S|H)) = \log(P(s_1,s_2,...,s_l)) + \log(P(l))$$

Did I miss anything??

> [image]

Here is the table of probability (idealized) predicted by the model:

> [image]